# Issue getting character in char array at index in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I've been having a issue in one of my functions which is supposed to get the characters in a char array.

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    char javaFileLocation[512];
    char cFileLocation[512];
    char cFileName[512];

    printf("Type in the location of the Java file you'd like to convert : \n\n");
    fgets(javaFileLocation, 512, stdin);
    removeLastChar(javaFileLocation);

    printf("Choose the location you want the resulting C file to be in : \n\n");
    fgets(cFileLocation, 512, stdin);
    removeLastChar(cFileLocation);

    printf("Choose the name for the new C file : \n\n");
    fgets(cFileName, 512, stdin);
    removeLastChar(cFileName);

    FILE * javaFile = fopen(javaFileLocation, "r");
    if(javaFile == NULL) {
       printf("The java file you specified does not exist!: ");
       perror("fopen error: ");
       return 1;
    }
    strcat(cFileLocation, cFileName);
    FILE * cFile = fopen(cFileLocation, "w");
    if(cFile == NULL) {
       printf("The c file was not able to be created!: ");
       perror("fopen error: ");
       return 1;
    }
    printf("file has been successfully created. \n");
    int maxSize = 0;
    char contents[512];
    while (fgets(contents, sizeof(contents), javaFile)) {
        maxSize = maxSize + strlen(contents) + 1;
    }
    char translated[maxSize];
    rewind(javaFile);
    while (fgets(contents, sizeof(contents), javaFile)) {
       getTranslation(contents, translated);
    }
    fprintf(cFile, translated);
    fclose(javaFile);
    fclose(cFile);
    return 0;
}

void removeLastChar(char * word){
    word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0';
}

void getTranslation(char line[], char translation[]){
    char current[strlen(line)];
    int index;
    for(index = 0; index < strlen(line); index++){
        strcat(translation, line[index + 1]);
    }
}
```

My issue is happening in getTranslation and is the line `strcat(translation, line[index + 1]);`.  The code runs, but when it reaches that line, the program freezes, does nothing, and I get this as the return code in my console:

`Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 24.007 s`

If anyone knows what's wrong and can help me it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `strcat` expects a string as the second argument. `line[index + 1]` is a single character.

Comment: Replace all `removeLastChar(javaFileLocation);` with `javaFileLocation[strcspn (javaFileLocation, "\n")] = 0;` -- no need for a function call -- and this will handle `EOF` - where your function invokes Undefined Behavior attempting to index `word[-1] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, (0xC0000005) is an [access violation](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-memory-access-violation.html).

This is Bad.  It means you're writing outside "legal" memory.  It will crash your program.

Among other things, I would modify getTranslation() to ensure that, however often you append (strcat) to "translated", you *NEVER* exceed 511 characters (remember - you always need to reserve an extra byte for the null termination character).

Answer (score 0):

Your `index` goes from 0 to `strlen(line)`, but since you are adding +1 you are effectivelly iterating from 1 to `strlen(line)`, and thus the last iteration will fail when it tries to access `line[strlen(line)+1]`. But there is a more important issue which has already been pointed out in the comments: strcat takes a `const char*` as the second argument, but you are passing a `char`. Does your code even compile?